# Print url to default featured image

Tags: filters, post-thumbnails

I'm trying to setup a fallback image for featured image.
The main problem I have is miss of filter for `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`. I'm using this function to echo thumb url in many-many templates, because it is easy customizable. So, this is not a solution to make an if-condition for each usage. And even to set default image for blank featured image, because it may be changed.
I see that I might apply filter to `get_post_thumbnail_id()`, but most likely I need an external URL to this fallback image, hardcoded in this theme. But, even if I can't apply external image, how can I make default image for `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` function?

Comment: what is the code that you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can't, not possible. There is no filter for `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` or `get_post_thumbnail_id()`.

However you could apply a filter to `get_metadata()` which `get_post_thumbnail_id()` uses, and return the id of another attachment that you want to use as the default thumbnail. But I don't recommend this it's a bit hacky.

I think you should refactor your code and just make a function to check if get_post_thumbnail_id returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps hook into `save_post`?

1. check that featured image is NOT set during save
2. then set default featured image
   post_meta `_thumbnail_id`

Reference:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post
- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L34 (@see `get_post_thumbnail_id`)